# Visual Studio 2015 RTM freeze issues during web debugging

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-debugging, freeze

I have a freeze-issue with my Visual Studio 2015 RTM when I debug script files (TypeScript/Javascript) in web projects (scripts only - no server-side code/ASP.NET).

Adding a breakpoint during debugging freezes the IDE for 4-6 seconds. Stepping through code works fine but freezes again if the IDE needs to switch to another script-file when I press F10. I installed VS2015 on another machine. Same thing.

My project did not have this issue in VS2013.
What's the best way to investigate freeze-issues?